# How to control line breaks in alterqcm

Tags: line-spacing, alterqcm

Here's a minimal working example to clarify my problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{alterqcm}

\begin{document}
\begin{alterqcm}[symb = \dingsquare,lq=6cm,language=english] 
\AQquestion{This is a long question, which can be written over serveral lines with line breaks.}{% 
{One short proposition 1},
{A longer proposition 2, still fits},
{A really long proposition 3, which does not fit in one line and has this really wide spacing between lines},
{Just another short proposition 4}}  
\end{alterqcm}

\end{document}
```

[image: my spacing problem]

So I have this weird big spacing when my answer needs more than one line. When I `\smash` the propositions every answer will be written in one line, ignoring the right margin.
How can I force `alterqcm` to reduce the vertical spacing to the last line?

Comment: I don't think `alterqcm` supports line wrapping in the second column.

Comment: You can put the answer in a parbox, `{\parbox{6cm}{proposition 3}}`, but you have to specify the width and the checkbox will be centered instead of top-aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If manual linebreaks are acceptable, then one can `\Longunderstack` the answers.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{alterqcm,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{alterqcm}[symb = \dingsquare,lq=6cm,language=english] 
\AQquestion{This is a long question, which can be written over serveral lines with line breaks.}{% 
{One short proposition 1},
{A longer proposition 2, still fits},
{\Longunderstack[l]{A really long proposition 3, which\\ 
  does not fit in one line and has this\\ 
  really wide spacing between lines}},
{Just another short proposition 4}}  
\end{alterqcm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And as maryjn indicated in comments, a `\parbox` can be used.  If one uses the `[t]` option, then alignment is OK, as well

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{alterqcm,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{alterqcm}[symb = \dingsquare,lq=6cm,language=english] 
\AQquestion{This is a long question, which can be written over serveral lines with line breaks.}{% 
{One short proposition 1},
{A longer proposition 2, still fits},
{\parbox[t]{6cm}{A really long proposition 3, which
  does not fit in one line and has this
  really wide spacing between lines}},
{Just another short proposition 4}}  
\end{alterqcm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Both solutions just worked out and give the same result with the top-option for `parbox`. For `\Longunderstack` I had to install the `listofitems` package in the MiKTex Manager manually (if anybody comes across the same problem).

Comment: @Karla Yes, `listofitems` (an awesome package that I had the privilege of participating in the development of) is employed by `stackengine` (which I wrote).